# What acts could an Extremist Anti-Peace group commit to make two friendly nations go to War

Tags: society, warfare, medieval, government, military

If there was an Anti-Peace group that wanted two neighboring nations to go to war, what kind of actions could they take?

They're malicious, fueled with hate, and they have little to no empathy for the sanctity for life, willing to do anything to make these nations go to war.

There is no advance technology like guns, motorized vehicles, communication devices, etc..

One nation is almost twice as large as the other and they have been relatively peaceful with each other with only minor territorial grievances.

*So my question boils down to:*

**What kind of acts could they commit that would warrant war, that they could then pass the blame to another nation?**

Comment: A nation state is a much younger concept than you might realize. They were born well after guns became popular. The idea of an extremist group that large is also completely out of time. That there are two nations and the rest is irrelevant is pure fantasy. Your world is completely different from our world. Why am I telling you what you already know? You have a strange world with a large group of irrational people. Please go into details. You must know the trojan war. So please clarify why you don't go with what the first world builders went. This is maybe the oldest solved problem in wb

Comment: Besides being a request for the community to develop the plot of your story for you, I would note in real history the word "nation" most definitely did not mean "state" in those times when there were no guns. The Roman Empire was not a "nation"; Athens was not a "nation"; Lacaedemon (called Sparta in popular movies) was not a "nation". And in those times, 15,000 men would be sizeable army; we still marvel at Xenophon's story of the [expedition of the 10,000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anabasis_(Xenophon)). Those 15,000 men could *make the war* themselves.

Comment: @AlexP this is a great point, however I wonder what 15000 people means. So let's go even further. 15000 able and free men ready to go to war? That's an army. 15000 random people that sympathize but well, have to obey the rules of their time - whatever they might be - living perhaps between serfdom and slavery, some women and elderly, most of them too poor to buy weapons? This 15000 extremist thing is completely baffling

Comment: @Raditz_35: It's a time before guns. I don't really see a war-thirsty organization with lots of female members, and I also don't see so many slaves and serfs having so much free time that they can actually think and conspire. A handful of particulary pampered slaves, for example, [70 gladiators in a training facility in Capua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartacus), yes; fifteen thousand of them, no way. In those times, people who had the time and inclination to take part in large scale organizations were free men. (And the elderly are very seldom extremists.)

Comment: For an historical example sort-of kind-of similar to what the question asks, see [Sicarii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicarii); but note that 15,000 is too large by two orders of magnitude. Questions: Do you really care about such a large number? Do they have to *want* to start a war between two powers? Because if those two requests can be waved I can provide historical examples of great wars with heavy consequences which started because of the actions of a relatively small number of people.

Comment: It seems there was a error on my part of adding information that wasn't pertinent to my intended inquiry. I corrected the question and I apologize for the inclusion of inaccurate information to my original intent. Thank you for all of your feedback and I found all the things you had to say very helpful.

Comment: The king may tolerate disagreement. However, it's unlikely the king will tolerate the subversion and political manipulation implied by this question. Many of the conspirators will be eventually hanged (or impaled or beheaded) as an example of the king's strong feelings about such treasons.

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1: Create global superpowers through warfare**

I'm reminded of the Cold War, in which after defeating Germany, the USA and USSR entered a period of escalating hostility. If you grew your militia to such an extent that it became dangerous - or you modified your premise to make it a third, violent country - then the ensuing war could incentivize the two nations to become competing superpowers. They could work together to defeat their mutual enemy, but ideological differences would soon emerge. Combined with increased militarization, they may fight for control of what's left of the region.

**Option 2: Gain direct political control, then attack**

The time period of your question isn't clear, but you can tailor this solution accordingly. If each nation is a monarchy, the antagonists can marry into the royal families. If each nation is democratic, your antagonists can seek office. The most effective way to start a war is for the government to declare war directly.

**Option 3: Spread incendiary rhetoric / exploit differences**

Your group can use the existing social, political, and cultural differences between the two nations to promote fear. The use of violent rhetoric and fearmongering tactics will certainly promote some violence.

**Frame challenge: There are easier ways to incite violence.**

If your group craves violence for the sake of violence, it might conduct guerilla-style attacks on its own. A full-on war would be the best-case scenario, but it's hard to achieve. Also, as AlexP noted in the comments, 15,000 people may considered an army in its own right.

Answer (score 3):

**False Flag**

The concept of a false flag attack gets abused a lot by conspiracy theorists peddling absurdities, but there are historical precedents in which bad actors have dressed or passed themselves off as a different party in order to incite greater violence. The most famous example being at the very start of WWII with the Gleiwitz Incident, in which German soldiers staged attacks against German radio stations posing as Poles so that Hitler could incite the nation to war.

So in your premodern setting your extremists could pose as soldiers from both nations and launch brutal attacks against civilians in both nations. They should carry the banners of lords from the respective nation, and to attack targets that would incite moral outrage.

They should leave nothing but charred temples and houses strewn with the brutalized corpses of peasants and a few violated survivors who will relay what the raiders bragged about, which is their (false) allegiance to the opposite nation. Do this quickly enough and soon both nations will demand blood

Comment: Agree, was just about to post False Flag Ops. Historically corsairs would have a stash full of flags to pick one for the occasion.

Comment: @Gustavo Corsairs really were tricky bastards